# Counting the occurrence of a special character, numbers and letters on a user-specified string

Tags: java, regex

Can you help me about my code? its too difficult my problem is to count the occurrence of a special character, numbers and letters on a user-specified string. if you wouldn't mind kindly share the code.

Example I will input this string: `$amplec0de123.c0m`. The output should be:

> The total number of special character is 2. The total number of letter is 10. The total number of numbers is 5.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far? Do you have some samples of what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: .. or a sample input and an expected output

Comment: Good day sir. example i will input this string : $amplec0de123.c0m. The output should be. The total number of special character is 2. The total number of letter is 10. The total number of numbers is 5. Kindly help me with that problem sir please i use java language right now

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Whatever expression you would like to count put it in a simple regex like `/red/g`

```
var   es = "There is a woman in red who listens to simply red and her name is Mildred"
redCount = es.match(/red/g).length; // <- 3
```